# How to send posted data as parameter to class method in Slim Framwork

Tags: php, slim

This is my class:

```
class Order {

    public function insert($data)
    {
        ...
    }   
}
```

I have posted data and I want to send this to my method that is in a class:

```
$app->post('/insert-order', '\Order:insert');
```

I am trying to make this works like this example:

```
$app->post('/insert-order', function() use ($app) {

   $req = $app->request();

   die(var_dump($req->post()));
});
```

In this case, when I have no class, works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by marking `$app` as global inside your class.

```
class Order {
    public function insert()
    {
        global $app;
        var_dump($app->request->post());
    }
}
```

Using globals is usually considered bad habit. Another way of doing the same below.

```
class Order {
    public function insert($data)
    {
        var_dump($data);
    }
}

$app = new \Slim\Slim();
$app->post("/insert-order", function() use ($app) { 
    $order = new Order();
    $data = $app->request->post();
    $order->insert($data);
});

$app->run();
```

Comment: You can also use Slim's getInstance() method: `$data = \Slim\Slim::getInstance()->request->post();`

Comment: Ooh damn! This is beautiful! Thanks bro!